# Grow / Zoom VB.NET Form

Tags: vb.net, upgrade, screen-resolution

Is there an easy way to grow / zoom a VB.NET application and all controls within it to fill a larger screen resolution (or must I adjust each form element individually)?

NOTE: Adjusting the resolution back is not a permanent (or preferred) option in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't design your forms so they always fill the screen.  Your customer has bought that nice expensive monitor to see more windows, not more of your form.

A well designed form is otherwise always resizable.  Use the Anchor and Dock properties, TableLayoutPanel and FlowLayoutPanel to ensure that your controls move and size themselves properly.  If your customer wants it big, she'll just click the Maximize button.

Comment: My program controls the in-house testing of our product.  It is important that the technicians easily see several numbers on the display from the equipment connected to the machine.

Comment: Just change the form's Font property to a larger font.  It will grow, scaling the controls as well.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't realize changing the form Font size scaled everything else accordingly.